# Incomplete datasets - log shows nothing

Tags: apify

I have an actor with a cheerio-crawler that crawls a list of approx 5500 urls (urlList)

The urls are result pages where there is a script containing a json file. There is some text added to the json so its not "clean", and therefore I extract it in a const, and checks if there is a match in an "if" statement. If there is a match, I crawl.

Now. My problem is that the crawler stats + the logs, seems to indicate that all urls are crawled. Problem is they are not. In the logs I do see some timeouts (example below), but those urls are just put back on the request list. A url like "example.com" seems fine in the logs, and on lookup there is data + json on the page, but it is not outputted in the results.

I can't figure out whats wrong, but have a hunch that its the "if" statement that is doing something funky. Maybe the json is found but not loaded yet, or something else.

Could some of you clever heads give a helping hand?

**Stats example**
Crawler final request statistics: {"avgDurationMillis":2554,"perMinute":580,"finished":5445,"failed":0,"retryHistogram":[5151,276,18]}

**Timeout example:**
Error: CheerioCrawler: request timed out after 30 seconds. etc. etc.

```
const Apify = require('apify');

Apify.main(async () => {
  const requestList = new Apify.RequestList({ sources: urlList })
  await requestList.initialize();

  const crawler = new Apify.CheerioCrawler({
    requestList,
    useApifyProxy: true,
    handlePageFunction: async ({ $, request }) => {

      const jsonString = $('script:contains("__thisvalue__")').text();
      if (jsonString.match(/\[{[\d\D]*}\]/) !== null) {
        const json = JSON.parse(jsonString.match(/\[{[\d\D]*}\]/));
        let i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

          await Apify.pushData({
            //do some crawling
            url: request.url

          });
        }
      }
    },
    handleFailedRequestFunction: async ({ request }) => {
      console.log(`Copy of request: ${request}`);
    },
  });
  await crawler.run();
  return 'Done'

});
```

Comment: 1. Woud be nice to include the logs, dataset link etc.
2. I'm not sure why you loop over the json.length before pushing?
3. Timeout are normal if they don't happen for all URLs. There are by default 3 retries that should solve it.
4. The stats tell you that all URLs are processed till the end, some of them were retried once or twice before success.

Comment: Cant share the logs/dataset publicly but have sent them to you. I loop because the json has several objects, e.g. {id: 1, name: "name1"}, {id: 2, name: "name"}. So I loop to extract each object. 3 and 4. Exactly, and that is my main issue. Everything looks fine, but items are missing.

Comment: When debugging, the first rule is to always add logs. So add log if the jsonString is empty and also if it doesn't match. Also dump the HTML into key-value store so you exactly what you got back. Maybe you got captcha instead but you don't check for the content at all.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. See my solution below. Don't know if there is a better approach. Btw. agree with the logging part, I do have more logging when testing etc., but minimize logging when in production.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
This line:

```
if (jsonString.match(/\[{[\d\D]*}\]/) !== null)
```

I created the if to make sure that I crawled pages where there was the correct json string (e.g. the data that I want to crawl).

But sometimes the script hadn't output the data yet (maybe cheerio can be too fast?), so pages where there should be a result, did not get crawled, and because there was no error those urls were not put back on the request list for another run.

I simply changed the following line and deleted the whole if. Now the url gets re-evaluated 3 times if there is no data in the json, and all urls ends up getting crawled. Only caveat is that I now get errors in my logs with ***TypeError: Cannot read property 'xyz' of null.***

```
const jsonString = JSON.parse($('script:contains("__thisvalue__")').text().match(/{[\d\D]*}}/))
```

Comment: Cheerio cannot load "too fast" since it just loads the whole HTML file, nothing more, nothing less.

It is also a good idea to split your code into smaller variables and do checks on them. You can then throw a custom error instead of "cannot read property...". Like one variable for the script, another for the match etc. Then you know exactly what hapenned and can debug why that part was different

Comment: Hi Lukas. Gotcha. Sometimes it seems the script-tag is just empty on first run, that’s why I thought that cheerio could be too fast. Is it possible to manually put a url back on requestlist? Like “if jsonString == null...” then put request.url back on requestlist? The problem is that of the 5.500 urls some will always have empty scripts, while others seems to be momentarily empty in like 3-4 % of the cases.

Comment: We solve this by simply throwing an error `throw new Error('No script found');`. The request will be automatically retried later. If this happens a lot, you can also increase the `maxRequestRetries` option of CherioCrawler. (default is 3)